# Seperate list into row and column based on delimiter

Tags: python, list, loops, row, delimiter

I have a list of emails I wanted to split into two columns.

```
df = [Smith, John <jsmith@abc.com>; Moores, Jordan <jmoores@abc.com>; 
Manson, Tyler <tmanson@abc.com>; Foster, Ryan <rfoster@abc.com>]

list = df.split(';')
for i in list
print (i)
```

Expected result is to have two columns, one for name, and one for email:

```
Name             Email
Smith, John      jsmith@abc.com
Moores, Jordan   jmoores@abc.com
Manson, Tyler    tmanson@abc.om
Foster, Ryan     rfoster@abc.com`
```

Comment: You already used `split(';')` to separate lines, why cannot you use it again on each line for the comma?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the output of your current code so other can better help debug.

Comment: So your `df` is a string? Why are there brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT use `list` as a variable name; there's just no reason to. Here is a way to do it, assuming your input is a string:

```
data = "Smith, John <jsmith@abc.com>; Moores, Jordan <jmoores@abc.com>; Manson, Tyler <tmanson@abc.com>; Foster, Ryan <rfoster@abc.com>"

# Do not call things list as "list" is a keyword in Python
l1 = data.split(';')
res = []
for i in l1:
    splt = i.strip().split()
    res.append([" ".join(splt[:2]), splt[-1][1:-1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Name", "Email"])
```

Comment: @Pho6 No problem. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem!